# Pandas sparse DataFrame plotting

Tags: python, pandas

I am exploring the possibilities of sparse DataFrames and I stumbled upon a very basic problem.

When I plot a series like that it works
    `plt.plot(ser)`

But when I change the series to sparse it doesn't work anymore but I receive this error:

`Expected dimension <= 1 data`

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

ser = pd.Series(np.random.rand(10))

plt.plot(ser) # works    

ser = ser.to_sparse()

plt.plot(ser) # not working
```

Comment: Can you share an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem?

Comment: Thank you, I added an  MVCE.

Comment: `import numply as np`, `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`, `import pandas as pd` ?

Comment: `plt.plot(ser.to_sparse().to_dense())` is not a solution ?

Comment: Yes, thats a "solution" but I am trying to get some performance gains using sparse data formats while plotting etc and making it dense again defeats that thought.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Comment: @RThompson no sadly not. You?